# How to use ncu command to profile average time/usage/etc for a kernel repeating 10 times?

Tags: cuda, nsight

For example, I have a test program for 5 kernels:

```
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        kernel_1<<<...>>>(...); // warm up
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        kernel_1<<<...>>>(...); // to be measured
    }
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        kernel_5<<<...>>>(...); // warm up
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        kernel_5<<<...>>>(...); // to be measured
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Each kernel will run 20 times, but only the last 10 times need to be measured. And I need the average time/usage/statistics for the 10 times.
How to do it gracefully using ncu command line? Should I use cudaProfilerStart() / End() to assist?

I want the result to be written into an Excel file. I am a beginner, thank you for help.

Comment: Take a look a [nvbench](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvbench).

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this using multiple Nsight Compute runs:

1. Profile `kernel_1` but skip first 10 launches: `ncu -s 10 -k kernel_1 ...`
2. Profile `kernel_2` but skip first 10 launches: `ncu -s 10 -k kernel_2 ...`

et cætera. Option `-s N` allows you to skip the first `N` kernel launches, while taking in account the kernel name filter passed using option `-k <kernel-name>`.